# Isn't "www.website.com" same as "http://www.website.com" in android acitivity Intent?

Tags: android, android-intent

My virtual android device can't open new activity "www.youtube.com", but can open "http://www.youtube.com"

Are they not the same?

```
  public void onClick(View v){
         Intent gotowebsite = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("www.youtube.com") ) ;
         startActivity(gotowebsite) ;
```

this code above does not work, the button that listens to this click does not open anything.

"http://" is not same as "www"?
can someone explain why android does not recognize it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Are they not the same?

Obviously not, or Android would handle it the same way.

> "http://" is not same as "www"

They are not, and never have been. Ever.

`http://` is a protocol prefix or schema, as is `https://`, `ftp://`, `smb://` etc. This tells the device how to access the host which is about to follow.

`www.` by itself is meaningless, although it's generally used to indicate a web server when used in a fully qualified domain name (FQDN). However, you could also access it by means other than the `http` protocol.